# Name result of a function

Tags: r

In a function I created, at the end of the process I need to find the maxima of the data.

In this screenshot,[the values' name are [ 1 ]],[[ 2 ]] etc. 
[image: r screenshot]

And when I export them to excel, values are getting complicated.
[image: excel screenshot]

For example; I want to give 'two hours' name to [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfWj6.jpg)] 
And I want to see these names in the excel sheet.

Comment: Please edit this, past and future questions as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `names()` of your list...

```
(x <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) # an unnamed list
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 5

names(x) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e") # set list names to vector of names
x
$`a`
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3

$d
[1] 4

$e
[1] 5
```

However, the best way to do this depends on your function - which you haven't provided...